# how provide data for zsh completion system

Tags: zsh

Is there any standard way of providing list of program switches, so it would be possible for zsh to determine possible completions? Or must it provided directly to zsh developers and only they can add completions to zsh?

Answer (score 2):

Your first stop should be `man zshcompsys`.

Then you could look at an example such as `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_vim`.

Answer (score 2):

The Z-Shell doesn't *automatically* know what possible switches work with which binary files. As far as I'm aware, there's no standard way for a shell to determine this.

ZSH works by using *completion functions*, which are written for specific programs. For example, `zsh` ships with completion functions for `ssh`, `cvs`, `git`, `ls`, etc.

If you want to *look* at these completion functions, you can. If you're in a `zsh` shell, `echo $fpath` to see the `function path` that `zsh` uses to load completion functions. There's a directory called `/usr/local/share/zsh/4.3.17/function` (location may vary for distributions / zsh versions), which has a bunch of files beginning with `_` - `_ssh`, `_cvs`, etc. Those are the completion functions.

One massive clue that these are not generated automatically comes from a comment in the `_ssh` completion function that ships with `4.3.17` (may or may not be in your specific version):

```
# Completions currently based on OpenSSH 5.9 (released on 2011-09-06).
#
# TODO: update ssh-keygen (not based on 5.9)
# TODO: sshd, ssh-keyscan, ssh-keysign
```

#### Providing completion for the Z-Shell: using `fpath`

You can write your own completion functions, and developers can write functions for their programs and submit to the `zsh` developers for inclusion. Z-Shell completion functions go somewhere on the `fpath`.

Answer (score 2):

If the program, say `foobar`, follows GNU conventions for options, you can use:

```
compdef _gnu_generic foobar
```

Otherwise you can write your own functions. The easiest to use IMO is `_describe`.

1. Create a file `_foobar` with contents:

```shell
#compdef foobar

cmds=(
'--one:option one'
'--four:option four'
'no-slashes:options do not need to start with a slash'
)

_describe 'foobar' cmds
```

1. Place the file somewhere in your `$fpath`
2. Add `compdef _foobar foobar`

Answer (score 0):

If You are using ruby with the optparse package there is a hidden flag `--*-completion-zsh=NAME` that will output all that is needed for the completion for that ruby program. Store it in a file named _NAME somewhere in your `$fpath` and it will work. NAME should be exactly what your program/script is called.

I use a folder in my `$HOME` for that and added the path to `$fpath` but that required an additional line in my `.zshrc`:

```
autoload -U ~/.completion/*(:t)
```